# What are all of Zoidberg's abillities?

Tags: futurama, zoidberg

Over the course of Futurama, Zoidberg is shown to have many special powers. What are all of them?

<sub>This isn't a list question according to the FAQ, as there is a finite list of them making the question answerable</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://theinfosphere.org/Decapodians

It will show you his anatomy (that will show what he can do).

- Super Hard shell
- Instant Molting
- Ink Defense
- Can breathe underwater
- Survive in intense pressure
- Stink Gland that makes a bad smell when he gets bored
- Second head (inside his own head)
- Empathy Bladder
- Can eat from either two ecosystems (fresh and saltwater)
- Throws up pearls
- He also has a berserk mode when he is filled with male jelly (mating season)

Comment: I am not looking for his anatomy. I am looking for a complete list of his special powers. Such as spraying ink, or stink. - The link lists some, as well as lots of extra info, and is not complete.

Comment: @DampeS8N That is in the Anatomy. Seriously any special powers from anything comes from its anatomy. And it can never be complete until Futurama says its complete.

Comment: I agree with you, but I seek a consolidation of the information. A simple list of his abilities, and not a course is decapodian anatomy. Distill that from the link into the answer and I'll reverse my DV and select this answer.

Comment: +1 since that looks like a list of abilities to me

Comment: @JustinC I just added that.